# Use javascript to control multiple items in a slide show from single button presses

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with a couple forward/previous buttons setup to spin a few circles and display a corresponding DIV container. The circle spinning part seems to work fine, but I can't get the text box to transition forward or backward when the buttons are clicked.

Strangely though if I click the forward button a few times the previous button does work temporarily. That seems to indicate that the index register is increasing, but something isn't linked up properly and maybe the whole thing isn't looping around at the end of the list.

What did I get wrong?

```js
var _PARENT_ANGLE = 0;
var _CHILD_ANGLE = 0;
var slideIndex = 0;

function showSlide(slideIndex) {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}

function nextSlide() {
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }
  showSlide(slideIndex);
}

function previousSlide() {
  slideIndex--;
  if (slideIndex < 0) {
    slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
  }
  showSlide(slideIndex);
}

function scanForClass(className) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  var firstElement = elements[0];
  firstElement.style.display = "block";
}

scanForClass("slide");

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', function() {
    _PARENT_ANGLE -= 90;
    _CHILD_ANGLE += 90;
    document.querySelector("#parent").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _PARENT_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#a-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#b-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#c-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#d-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    nextSlide();
});

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener('click', function() {
    _PARENT_ANGLE += 90;
    _CHILD_ANGLE -= 90;
    document.querySelector("#parent").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _PARENT_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#a-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#b-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#c-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#d-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    previousSlide();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Circle Loop Example</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        :root {
            --circle-purple: #7308ae; 
            --circle-red: #fd0000;
            --circle-blue: #1242a6;
            --circle-green: #06ca04;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #7af;
        }
        .outer {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .middle {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 100px;  /* -450px */
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -150px;
            margin-left: -150px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .button {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 0px 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        .button:hover {
            color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        }
        .prev {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0%;
        }
        .next {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 0%;
        }
        .circle {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 70px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
        }
        .purple {color: var(--circle-purple);border-color: var(--circle-purple);}
        .red {color: var(--circle-red);border-color: var(--circle-red);}
        .blue {color: var(--circle-blue);border-color: var(--circle-blue);}
        .green {color: var(--circle-green);border-color: var(--circle-green);}
        .slide {display: none;}

        #parent {
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: none;
            outline: 80px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            outline-offset: -40px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
        }
        #a-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            top: -80px;   /* -child size - 20% */
            left: 100px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #a-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #a-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #a-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-purple);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #a-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-purple);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #b-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            top: 100px;   /* -child size/2 */
            right: -80px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #b-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #b-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #b-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-red);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #b-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-red);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #c-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            bottom: -80px;   /* -child size/2 */
            left: 100px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #c-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #c-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #c-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-blue);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #c-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-blue);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #d-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            top: 100px;   /* -child size/2 */
            left: -80px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #d-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #d-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #d-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-green);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #d-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-green);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas">
        <div id="a-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>Nam volutpat efficitur semper. Nullam aliquet tortor id mollis vehicula.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="b-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>Vestibulum ac blandit libero, vel lacinia magna. Vestibulum nec commodo magna.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="c-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>In dictum, lectus nec rhoncus viverra, est elit vehicula leo, at bibendum mi enim in sem.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="d-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>Aenean mollis leo sit amet libero volutpat, vitae cursus arcu ultrices.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <button id="rotate-left" class="button prev">&#10094;</button>
        <button id="rotate-right" class="button next">&#10095;</button>
        <div class="middle">
            <div id="parent">
                <div id="a-wrapper">
                    <div id="a-icon" class="circle purple">1</div>
                </div>
                <div id="b-wrapper">
                    <div id="b-icon" class="circle red">2</div>
                </div>
                <div id="c-wrapper">
                    <div id="c-icon" class="circle blue">3</div>
                </div>
                <div id="d-wrapper">
                    <div id="d-icon" class="circle green">4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Everything you have done is perfect but the `slides` to be globally declared instead you made that function scope.

Chaget the `slides` variable to global but putting top of code.

```js
      var _PARENT_ANGLE = 0;
var _CHILD_ANGLE = 0;
var slideIndex = 0;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");//add this
function showSlide(slideIndex) {
    
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}

function nextSlide() {
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex >= slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 0;
  }
  showSlide(slideIndex);
}

function previousSlide() {
  slideIndex--;
  if (slideIndex < 0) {
    slideIndex = slides.length - 1;
  }
  showSlide(slideIndex);
}

function scanForClass(className) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
  var firstElement = elements[0];
  firstElement.style.display = "block";
}

scanForClass("slide");

document.querySelector(".next").addEventListener('click', function() {
    _PARENT_ANGLE -= 90;
    _CHILD_ANGLE += 90;
    document.querySelector("#parent").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _PARENT_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#a-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#b-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#c-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#d-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    nextSlide();
});

document.querySelector(".prev").addEventListener('click', function() {
    _PARENT_ANGLE += 90;
    _CHILD_ANGLE -= 90;
    document.querySelector("#parent").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _PARENT_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#a-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#b-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#c-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    document.querySelector("#d-wrapper").style.transform = 'rotate(' + _CHILD_ANGLE + 'deg)';
    previousSlide();
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Circle Loop Example</title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        :root {
            --circle-purple: #7308ae; 
            --circle-red: #fd0000;
            --circle-blue: #1242a6;
            --circle-green: #06ca04;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #7af;
        }
        .outer {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .middle {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 100px;  /* -450px */
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            text-align: center;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-top: -150px;
            margin-left: -150px;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        .button {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: relative;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            margin: 0px 20px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
            border: 1px solid transparent;
            z-index: 10;
        }
        .button:hover {
            color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        }
        .prev {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 0%;
        }
        .next {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 0%;
        }
        .circle {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 70px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px;
        }
        .purple {color: var(--circle-purple);border-color: var(--circle-purple);}
        .red {color: var(--circle-red);border-color: var(--circle-red);}
        .blue {color: var(--circle-blue);border-color: var(--circle-blue);}
        .green {color: var(--circle-green);border-color: var(--circle-green);}
        .slide {display: none;}

        #parent {
            position: relative;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
            border: none;
            outline: 80px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
            outline-offset: -40px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
        }
        #a-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            top: -80px;   /* -child size - 20% */
            left: 100px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #a-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #a-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #a-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-purple);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #a-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-purple);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #b-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            top: 100px;   /* -child size/2 */
            right: -80px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #b-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #b-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #b-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-red);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #b-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-red);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #c-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            bottom: -80px;   /* -child size/2 */
            left: 100px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #c-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #c-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #c-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-blue);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #c-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-blue);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #d-wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            transform: rotate(0deg);
            transition: transform 0.7s linear;
            top: 100px;   /* -child size/2 */
            left: -80px;   /* parent size/2 - child size/2 */
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #d-icon {
            position: relative;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: white;
            z-index: 3;
        }
        #d-description {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #d-description .box {
            max-width: 350px;
            left: 50%;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 7px solid var(--circle-green);
            margin: 30px auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }
        #d-description p {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: var(--circle-green);
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
    </style>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="canvas">
        <div id="a-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>Nam volutpat efficitur semper. Nullam aliquet tortor id mollis vehicula.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="b-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>Vestibulum ac blandit libero, vel lacinia magna. Vestibulum nec commodo magna.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="c-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>In dictum, lectus nec rhoncus viverra, est elit vehicula leo, at bibendum mi enim in sem.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="d-description" class="slide">
            <div class="box">
                <p>Aenean mollis leo sit amet libero volutpat, vitae cursus arcu ultrices.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
        <button id="rotate-left" class="button prev">&#10094;</button>
        <button id="rotate-right" class="button next">&#10095;</button>
        <div class="middle">
            <div id="parent">
                <div id="a-wrapper">
                    <div id="a-icon" class="circle purple">1</div>
                </div>
                <div id="b-wrapper">
                    <div id="b-icon" class="circle red">2</div>
                </div>
                <div id="c-wrapper">
                    <div id="c-icon" class="circle blue">3</div>
                </div>
                <div id="d-wrapper">
                    <div id="d-icon" class="circle green">4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```